# How can i use SUBSTR mysql function in Typeorm with select (SOLVED)

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

i am creating query which can bring 3 table relations results

```
this.invoicesRepo
      .createQueryBuilder('invoices')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('invoices.client', 'client')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('invoices.items', 'items')
      .select(['invoices.id', 'client.name'])
      .groupBy('invoices.id')
      .getMany();
```

which returns these results

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "client": {
      "name": "Goku"
    }
  }
]
```

but i want results like this

```
 // I WANT RESULTS
[
      {
        "id": 1,
        "client": {
          "name": "Gok"  // just 3 start letters 
        }
      }
   ]
```

i have written this query for that purpose but its just returning id

```
this.invoicesRepo
      .createQueryBuilder('invoices')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('invoices.client', 'client')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('invoices.items', 'items')
      .select(['invoices.id', 'SUBSTR(client.name,1,3)']) // not working
      .groupBy('invoices.id')
      .getMany();
```

how can i achive the upper results in typeorm and mysql

so i can summary it into simple question that how can i write this query in typeorm

```
select SUBSTR(name,1,3),items.invoiceId from client
inner join invoices on invoices.clientId = client.id
inner join items on items.invoiceId = invoices.id
group by items.invoiceId;
```

Answer (score 0):

**I HAVE GOT A SOLUTION**

for using substr function we should use getRaw function that typeorm provide
getRawOne() and getRawMany()

so the query will be like this

```
this.invoicesRepo
      .createQueryBuilder('invoices')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('invoices.client', 'client')
      .innerJoin('invoices.items', 'items')
      .select('invoices.id')
      .addSelect('SUBSTR(client.name,1,3)', 'client_name') //here
      .groupBy('items.invoiceId')
      .orderBy('invoices.created_at', 'ASC')
      .getRawMany();  //these is necessary if u using function like substr,concat etc
```

OUTPUT

```
[
  {
    "invoices_id": 1,
    "client_name": "Gok"
  },
  {
    "invoices_id": 2,
    "client_name": "Kha"
  },
  {
    "invoices_id": 3,
    "client_name": "Gok"
  }
]
```